# Why do votes on questions not affect tag score?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why are tag scores for each user only calculated by votes on their answers, and not their questions?

Over on my [tag page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/10654/matt?tab=tags), there are all the tags I've contributed to, and their corresponding scores.
Some are tags I've only given answers for, and so their score adds up to the overall number of votes:

- *danmachi* (**5**) - Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 5
- *mahouka-koukou* (**13**) - Gave 6 non-wiki answers with a total score of 13

Then there are some that have questions and answers, but only the question score counts:

- *identification-request* (**11**) - Asked one non-wiki question with a total score of 1. Gave 2 non-wiki answers with a total score of 11.

And those that have only questions, and therefore a score of 0:

- *kantai-collection* (**0**) - Asked 1 non-wiki question with a total score of 9.

I've taken a look on a few other meta sites and in the help center, but I've found no mention of why tag scores are calculated with answers only. Is there a reason for this? And in extension, why are tag badges bound to answer score only as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because upvotes on questions do not reflect your expertise in a field represented by the tag. To quote from [a Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156380/266094) from [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson):

> Including questions in the score isn't very viable because upvotes on questions generally only mean that you asked a good question. It doesn't necessarily prove any proficiency in the tag itself.

However, you can see your score in questions of the tag by hovering over the counter.

Comment: I think the logic behind this is a lot more clear on, say, Stack Overflow or Math than here. If I ask lots of questions about C++, that just means I'm confused by C++ (and who isn't?). If I ask a question about, say, Fate/Stay Night, I probably have a basic level of knowledge on Fate/Stay Night to have even formed the question, so it's less obvious that asking questions doesn't reflect expertise.

Comment: @Torisuda: You have a point, although all SE sites share the same software. On culture, recreational and science sites, asking reflects expertise as well, but wasn't taken into account on the original design of the tag score system.